# Is there a way to get multitouch events in AIR from OSX?

Tags: macos, flash, air

I'm trying to get multiple touch events from Mac OSX in AIR and AIR says it's not supported.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
trace("supportsTouchEvents:" + Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents);  // false
```

The Mac trackpad supports multitouch. Is there some way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multitouch Events are not supported on Mac, but gesture events (pan, rotate, swipe and zoom) are supported starting with Mac OS X 10.5.3 and later. So:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
trace("supportsGestureEvents :" + Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents);
trace("supportedGestures :" + Multitouch.supportedGestures);
```

More info here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html